How to scale the number of concurrent users of my LLM Chatbot RAG system for production
I have developed a chatbot using Azure OpenAI ChatGPT as LLM and AWS as the cloud provider for hosting the entire application, more details can be consulted in the image below.
Now, as the topology of my chatbot is a RAG (Retrieval Augmented Generation), the maximum amount of tokens per minute (80K tokens per minute) is easily reached when I have 6 or 7 users using the chatbot in parallel, this because due to the RAG topology, each input prompt of each user is always around 10K tokens.
Architecture:

As you can see from the image above, it is a multicloud architecture, indeed, the infrastructure is mainly deployed in AWS, while the LLM (ChatGPT) is from Azure.
I was thinking to deploy multiple ChatGPT endpoints in different Azure regions, but then I don't know how to load balance calls to different Azure ChatGPT endpoints.
Do you have any suggestion?
How can I scale the architecture to support more users in parallel?

Just thinking about this conceptually, why not have a function within your application that runs on EC2 which runs every time your application needs to make a call to Azure OpenAI and determines which of several OpenAI endpoints to return? A round-robin style of load balancing should not be difficult to achieve and at least offhand seems the best load distribution mechanism for this use case.

Which model is causing issues with quotas: ada-002, or GPT? Probably a GPT-4 32k as you mentioned 80k TPM, which is a standard limit for it. I'm surprised that you can't have more than 6-7 users.

To KonTheCat: do you think I can reach something similar more codeless using AWS services? Maybe a combination of services like ALB, API Gateway, etc?
To Nicolas R: yes I'm using ChatGPT-4, and I can easily reach the max tokens per minute with 7-8 users in parallel because I'm using a RAG architecture, so each input prompt is around 10K tokens.
